# Write correct MySQL query with SET

Tags: mysql

I have the following query:

```
select count(*)
from @table := (
    select table_name
    from information_schema.TABLES
    where table_schema = 'sbnp_phalanx_queue'
    order by CREATE_TIME desc
    limit 1
)
where mtime < DATE_SUB(Now(), INTERVAL 3 DAY);
```

But I get an error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '@table = (select table_name  from
>   information_schema.TABLES where table_schema =' at line 1

How to perform it correctly?

Comment: You can't use an expression for the table name in a query.

Comment: You have to do this using `PREPARE` and `EXECUTE` in a stored procedure.

Comment: It's so bad. I must execute It in one line (

Comment: Sorry, that's not the way MySQL work.

Comment: I don't understand your subquery. You're matching an exact table name, so why can't you just write `FROM sbnp_phalanx_queue` in the main query? Why do you need `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`, there can only be one table with that name.